# How to move System Reserved Flag to another partition?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, diskmanagement, partition, mbr

I have a Dell PE R310 that came with Windows 2008 R2 with a 2 GB FAT32 partition that I want to delete. But I can't because, because it currently has the "System" flag set. How do I move it to the 32mb partition I have, assuming to be the "System Reserved" or even break this 2GB drive down to make a new partition.

It's a show stopper for my Windows Backup, because there is a FAT32 drive in my system.

[image: Screenshot of my current disks]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest consulting with Dell before you do this.  this partition contains valuable recovery programming that you might want to keep so that you can repair your system in the future.

Answer (score 3):

A better question might have been...

> I can't backup because I've got a FAT32 partition I can't get rid of

...as that is your actual problem, and it's a much easier one to solve that the approach you seem to be taking as you could very well end up with an unbootable system if you continue down that path.

Instead, try converting the volume to NTFS

1. Assign the volume a drive letter from Disk Management, let's use `Z:\` for this example
2. Run the command `Convert Z: /fs:ntfs`
3. Remove the drive letter assignment from the volume.
4. Reboot your server. (you'll need to do this before you can configure your backup).

...and don't forget to test your backup once you've taken one.

---

p.s. A quick search here on ServerFault would have revealed [a number of similar questions](https://serverfault.com/search?q=backup%20server%20fat32) from people with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, it does solve one problem. But I really would like to move it.. because I could use the space as well.